# XML Payload gives 'The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.' error

Tags: automated-testing, c#, api

I'm attempting to create a test framework in c# to automate some of our API tests. Relatively new to this area so have come across an issue I can't solve. My XML payload is as below:

```
 <Order>
   <BillingAddress>
     <AddressLine1></AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2></AddressLine2>
     <City></City>
   </BillingAddress>
  <Items>
    <Item IsKit="false">
      <CountryVATRate></CountryVATRate>
      <Group></Group>
      <Reference></Reference>
 </Item>
 </Items>
</Order>
```

When I attempt to execute the above(using RestSharp) I get the below error:
*"System.Xml.XmlException: 'The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.'"*

The offending line of code is

```
        <Item IsKit="false">
```

...where the code in c# I have written is as below

```
        XElement items = new XElement("Items");
        items.Add(new XElement("Item IsKit =\"false\""
```

I believe the issue is because there are spaces between the words 'Item' and 'IsKit'....my question is how I would get around this in order for this element to be added to my test code?

Comment: Your `Items` tag is not closed and might be causing the issue.

Comment: sorry I didn't put the closing tag in the code example above. thanks for pointing that out, however I still have the original issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to make an element called 'Item IsKit =\"false\"'

it looks like you actually want to create an Element called Item with an  attribute called IsKit.

Try this:

`new XElement("Item",new XAttribute("IsKit", "False"))`

Docs are here
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute